Identify board found on eletronic diposal
I have found this board on a electronic disposal point on my college.
I'm not sure if it's working, but i'm very curious about it.
It has a display, 4 buttons(one is damaged), some leds, a PIC18F448T-I/PT processor, 1 RJ45 connector on the back(mxi 95001) and a 4 contact RJ connector which i could not identify.
I suppose is something like a development or learning purpose board, on the back i see "Programming Only" written. I tried to search the numbers on the back, but could not find this specific board online.
Which board this is? specific model or any guess for it's purpose
Considering it's working, how can i program it?
Update: There's only one RJ45 connector, the second one is a RJ connector with 6 contacts




research the microcontroller chip ... look for  programming circuits in the datasheets ... compare circuit to the board

Unlikely to be a developement or learning purpose board. If it were such, it would likely contain enough info what is the board name and what do the connectors do. It is likely a remote UI board for some system like burglar alarm or central heating etc, with LCD for menus and status display and a few buttons for using the menus. Apply power and see what it does. The U2 seems to be a CAN bus transceiver for the long haul bus. The MCU is likely read and write protected so it might be you can't reprogram it even if you had the tools. You may need to replace the MCU with an unlocked empty chip.

@Justme tried now to connect a ethernet cable from my computer to the mxi 95001, nothing happened.
I'm not sure if there's another way to power the board, or if i should connect the ethernet cable to another device to power it.
Or it can be broken

@LeonardoCBoar Please don't do that. You may damage your computer. The LCD board does not have an Ethernet port. Also, the Ethernet port of your computer cannot power this device, or any other device for that matter. So nothing will happen for sure. Do not connect things together just because the connectors allow them to be connected together. You also don't know yet how to power it, but it's likely from the 8P8C port you mistake being Ethernet port.

@Justme Oh..... Luckily nothing was damaged, i'll keep that in mind.
So to power it over the 8P8C port i would need a PoE adapter, that's right? Like this one? https://www.amazon.com/PLUSPOE-Injector-Ethernet-Adapter-Security/dp/B077QGTDLB

@LeonardoCBoar Of course not, because it is not an Ethernet device, it cannot be powered with a PoE adapter, and you don't know which pins are the supply pins and what voltage can be safely used. If you force feed it with 24V PoE adapter, it will likely go up in smoke.

It's a display board from an Eaton UPS.
See link for similar unit: https://cpwarehouse.com/products/eaton-1021648e-display-board

Unlikely to be a developement or learning purpose board.
If it were such, it would likely contain enough info what is the board name and what do the connectors do.
It is likely a remote UI board for some system like burglar alarm or central heating etc, with LCD for menus and status display and a few buttons for using the menus.
Apply power and see what it does.
The U2 seems to be a CAN bus transceiver for the long haul bus.
The MCU is likely read and write protected so it might be you can't reprogram it even if you had the tools. You may need to replace the MCU with an unlocked empty chip.
The 8P8C modular jack is not an Ethernet port. Do not connect a PC there.
It looks like the 8P8C jack (RJ45 is a misnormer anyway) is used for the CAN bus and maybe powering the unit from the remote system.
The 6P6C jack is the PIC programming connector, but the pins seem to be available on the 8-pin pinheader too.
So neither are called RJ connectors as RJ means a standard interface with modular jacks and these are not RJ interfaces. They are modular jack connectors, not RJ connectors.
It is likely that even if you do manage to reverse-engineer how to power it, it may not do anything as it's not seeing the remote system.
And even if you change the MCU or manage to reprogram the current MCU, be sure to reverse-engineer the display protocol first before destroying the original code or MCU so you know how to use it.

Thank you for your answer!
I think i'll not be able to do any reverse-engineer on the board, but i liked your suggestions.
I was able to remove the display, and if i find which model is it, i may try to make it work.
